# Slack Bot Randomly Going Offline In Slack While Status is Running in MS-BotFramework

Tags: bots, botframework, slack

I have a custom bot that was made in c# using Microsoft's bot framework. The bot has been running without problems for a few weeks until today. I can send the bot messages in Microsoft's bot framework site and it responds, but the bot is offline in Slack. I have tried to reauthorize, re-add, and re-publish the bot to Slack and none of the above are working. I'm thinking it might be a problem on Slack's end since the bot is still online and working in Microsoft's bot framework site.

Is anyone else having this problem or know what else I can do to try and get the bot to come back online in Slack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the problem still occurring for you?  There was a bug with the Slack connector that has been fixed.

Comment: The problem seems to have been fixed over the weekend so that is a possibility. How does the Skype connector tie into the Slack/bot communication?